# How to access nested conditional type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

The origin of the following autogenerated type is a GraphQL query:

```
export type OfferQuery = { __typename?: 'Query' } & {
  offer: Types.Maybe<
    { __typename?: 'Offer' } & Pick<Types.Offer, 'id' | 'name'> & {
        payouts: Array<
          { __typename?: 'Payout' } & Pick<
            Types.Payout,
            'weGet' | 'theyGet'
          > & {
              offer: { __typename?: 'Offer' } & Pick<Types.Offer, 'id'>;
              publisher: Types.Maybe<
                { __typename?: 'Publisher' } & Pick<Types.Publisher, 'id'>
              >;
              eventType: Types.Maybe<
                { __typename?: 'EventType' } & Pick<
                  Types.EventType,
                  'id' | 'name'
                >
              >;
            }
        >;
      }
  >;
};
```

Now I would like to reuse parts of the OfferQuery type in my react component, namely a payout element.

```
type Payout = OfferQuery['offer']['payouts'][number];
```

This however gives me an error `"Property 'payouts' does not exist on type 'Maybe{ __typename?: "Offer" | undefined; }..."`.

Do you have any suggestions on how to circumvent this issue and access payouts definition anyway?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  }
}

Typescript 4.1.3
```

Comment: Where did Types come from ? I'm unable to reproduce. I'd willing to bet from fp-ts

Comment: I don't understand the question, but I am not using fp-ts.

Comment: Please share reproducable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

> ```js
> type Payout = NonNullable<OfferQuery['offer']>['payouts'][number];
> ```
>
> because `Maybe` causes `OfferQuery['offer']` to be nullable, and so you need to wrap it with the `NonNullable` type util first:

---

### Interpreting the error-message

The error-message is unclear, because it does not reveal what `Maybe` actually means.

The definition of `Maybe`, will say:

```js
type Maybe<T> = T | null;
```

meaning when you try to get `payouts` from `OfferQuery['offer']`, you're also trying to get `payouts` from `null` (which doesn't exist). This is what the error-message is trying to communicate.

### GraphQL codegen and nullable

GraphQL codegen will (correctly) add `Maybe` to each field that is nullable in your GraphQL schema. This has the implication that when you use the type `OfferQuery['offer']` you will get both `null` AND the actual definition.
I.e. you're actually receiving `null` *together* with the rest:

```js
type ExampleWithMaybe = null | {
  payouts: { weGet: number; theyGet: number }[];
  /* ...the rest of the definition... */
};
```

instead of receiving what you likely expected:

```js
type ExampleWithoutMaybe = {
  payouts: { weGet: number; theyGet: number }[];
  /* ...the rest of the definition... */
};
```

So when you want to use the type `payouts` on `OfferQuery['offer']`, you need to remember that you have to exclude the `null`-value first, because `payouts` doesn't exist on `null`.

### The solution: Remove `null`

In order to get the type definition without `null`, you can use the type-util `NonNullable`, meaning we can rewrite `ExampleWithoutMaybe` from the above example like so:

```js
type ExampleWithMaybe = null | {
  payouts: { weGet: number; theyGet: number }[];
  /* ...the rest of the definition... */
};
type ExampleWithoutMaybe = NonNullable<ExampleWithMaybe>;
```

and to make it specific to your example:

```js
// ❌ `payouts` doesn't exist on `null`
// type Payout = OfferQuery['offer']['payouts'][number];

// ✅
type Payout = NonNullable<OfferQuery["offer"]>["payouts"][number];
```

Comment: Thank you very much `NonNullable` is more elegant then using `Exclude`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only solution is to exclude null and undefined before accessing the array element type:

```
type Payout = Exclude<OfferQuery['offer']['payouts'], null | undefined>[number];
```